# Getting a child element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi guys I have this code below, its a delete menu, which contains a further delete instance and delete instance and following.  I am trying to ge to the sub menus, delete this instance or delete this instance and following, but so far no luck.

```
<li class="context-menu-item context-menu-submenu icon icon-delete">
    <span>Delete</span>
    <ul class="context-menu-list " style="width: 213px; z-index: 10; top: -21px; left:245px;">
        <li class="context-menu-item icon icon-delete">
            <span>Delete This Instance</span>
        </li>
        <li class="context-menu-item icon icon-delete">
           <span>Delete This Instance and All Following</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

This is what I have so far

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon-delete").click()
```

....this works it finds the main delete menu and opens it

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//ul[@class='context-menu-list']/..//li[@class='icon delete' and text()='Delete This Instance']" ).click()
```

...this is where I get the error.

Comment: What error are u getting? Provide a traceback.

Comment: It just does not work because its not able to find the element... Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class=\'context-menu-item icon icon-delete\']/..//span[@text()=\'Delete This Instance\']"}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checked using **Firepath**, your xpath `"//ul[@class='context-menu-list']/..//li[@class='icon delete' and text()='Delete This Instance']"` didn't result in any element, hence the resulting exception.

You can use the below xpaths for retrieving the required elements:

1- To locate the **'Delete This Instance'** :

```
//li[contains(@class,'icon-delete')]//span[.='Delete This Instance']
```

2- To locate the **'Delete This Instance and All Following'** :

```
//li[contains(@class,'icon-delete')]//span[.='Delete This Instance and All Following']
```

Comment: This worked thank you, but can you please explain how the '.=' works I cannot find it in the python operators section.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. This is an xpath expression used to locate element(s) having exact innerHTML/text on the right hand side of it. For instance, In the first example, the expression will locate all **span element(s), under li, with exact innerHTML/text as "Delete This Instance".** I hope you got it. :)

Comment: Don't mention it.. Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='icon-delete']/span[text()='Delete This Instance']").click()
```